# Visual Studio Connection String - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I am transfering a Silverlight Application in Visual Studio 2010 from my old computer to my new computer, as I will no longer be programming on my old computer.

As I do not know how to transfer databases, I have completely remade the database on my new computer in MS Server 2008 R2.

When I load the Management Studio of Server 2008 R2, the 'Connect To Server' Dialog Box is accessed with the following info:

```
Server Type: Database Engine
Server Name: COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESSR2
Authentication: Windows Authentication
Username: jonas_000 [This is greyed out]
Password: [This is blank and greyed out]
```

Once it connects you can find my database under the 'Databases' tab and it is labeled 'MyDatabase'.

So when I go into my Visual Studio 2010 Express Silverlight project and look in the 'Database Explorer' pane, I have connected to this R2 database and it shows 'computer\sqlexpressr2.MyDatabase.dbo', and I can see all the tables I have created.

Now the Question.

In my project's Web.config file I have the following (which is for the OLD computer's setup):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="mydatabaseConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\DB_MyWebSite.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

What should my new connectionStrings look like?

I cannot even see a mdf file on my new computer relating to MyDatabase.

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: Stop using `user instance` and `attachdbfilename`. You should be connecting to the *logical* name of the database on the instance of SQL Server you have installed, not attaching some copy of the .mdf file every time you run your program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="mydatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=COMPUTER\SQLEXPRESSR2;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

or

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="mydatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESSR2;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

or

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="mydatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESSR2;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The providerName attribute may be optional.

Also, you should run your app as jonas_000 for this to work (which is probably what you do when pressing F5 in Visual Studio).

Comment: You are the best. I have spent all day trying to figure this out. It was the SECOND one, ie .\SQLEXPRESSR2. Thanks again. This really means a lot to me.